# Scala async calculation exercise

Tags: scala, asynchronous, nonblocking

I have outlined the problem below. Method `calculate` represents a calculation that is to run `subCalc1` and `subCalc2` asynchroniously, and `mainCalc` that will be passed results from the last two 'sub' calculations. Significantly, before starting these calculations a preliminary calculation `isCalcNecessary` is to return a Boolean. If true, the calculation will continue and eventually return Future[Some[Result]]. If preliminary calculation returns false, it should return Future[None], as to illustrate that calculation was not necessary. This small algorithm should be maximally asynchronious.

```scala
def isCalcNecessary:Future[Boolean] = ...
def subCalc1(param:Param):Future[SubResult1] = ...
def subCalc2(param:Param):Future[SubResult2] = ...
def mainCalc(subResult1:SubResult1, subResult2:SubResult2):Future[Result] = .

def calcute(param:Param):Future[Option[Result]] = for {
  necessary <- isCalcNecessary(param)
  if necessary // this illustration fails at runtime if 'necessary' is false
  subResult1 <- subCalc1(param)
  subResult2 <- subCalc2(param)
  result <- mainCalc(subResult1, subResult2)
} yield Some(result)
```

The above illustration fails at runtime with (`NoSuchElementException: Future.filter predicate is not satisfied (Future.scala:312)`), if the `if necessary` conditional is not satisfied.

How would you write this algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
isCalcNecessary(param).flatMap { necessary => 
  if (necessary) 
    for {
      subResult1 <- subCalc1(param)
      subResult2 <- subCalc2(param)
      result <- mainCalc(subResult1, subResult2)
    } yield Some(result)
  else
    future(None)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to nest *for-comprehensions*

```
def calculate(param:Param):Future[Option[Result]] = for {
  necessary <- isCalcNecessary(param)
  endResult <- if (necessary) for {
      subResult1 <- subCalc1(param)
      subResult2 <- subCalc2(param)
      result     <- mainCalc(subResult1, subResult2)
    } yield Some(result)
    else future(None)
} yield endResult
```